# Dual Boot Ubuntu 15.10 with Windows 10 (Can't see partitions in Windows)

Tags: partitioning, 15.10, windows-10, ntfs-3g

I Used the "install ubuntu alongside windows boot manager" option to download ubuntu yesterday (after hours of confusion from reading about manually adding partitions).

I think I allowed 65GB (using the slider during installation) for Ubuntu and the rest for Windows. (I have 300GB usable HDD space).

After it finished installing, I tried booting in to each OS and they worked perfectly. The problem is, I am unable to see any of my Windows files and documents from Ubuntu.

When I click that Hard drive icon on Ubuntu, I get this:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/atlanta-thinkpad/BED68EB6D68E6F09: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda4" "/media/atlanta-thinkpad/BED68EB6D68E6F09"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Edited:

I can now see the ubuntu partitions after diabling fast startup in windows, but the partitions are empty.

Comment: If you read the message and follow the instruction, you will be able to mount the partition. Additionally, add the result of `lsblkid`.

Comment: Thanks, I disabled fast startup in windows and now I can see the Ubuntu partitions. The problem is those partitions  show as having 100% free space available. The only partition that doesn't have 100% free space is the C drive with my windows OS on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "see" (mount) the windows disk on Ubuntu, just follow the instructions you got:

> The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
>   Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
>   read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

If tou want to mount your ext3/4 linux partitions on windows, I googled [that](http://www.techgainer.com/how-to-mount-and-access-linux-partitions-ext4ext3ext2-in-windows-explorer-easily/) for you